# TypeError: string indices must be integers - Parsing JSON

Tags: python, json

I am having some trouble with the following JSON and reading the data, having looked though some of the other questions nothing seems to come up with a solution unless I am missing something..

Help always appreciated :)

JSON:

```
{"ships":{"2":{"name":"Asp","alive":true,"id":2},"3":{"starsystem":{"systemaddress":"670417429889","id":"670417429889","name":"Diaguandri"},"station":{"id":3223343616,"name":"Ray Gateway"},"name":"SideWinder","alive":true,"id":3},"12":{"starsystem":{"systemaddress":"18263140541865","id":"73228","name":"Barnard's Star"},"station":{"id":128147960,"name":"Miller Depot"},"name":"Viper_MkIV","alive":true,"id":12},"13":{"starsystem":{"systemaddress":"673101653409","id":"673101653409","name":"Brestla"},"station":{"id":3224813312,"name":"Roed Odegaard Port"},"name":"Type7","alive":true,"id":13},"14":{"starsystem":{"systemaddress":"673101653409","id":"673101653409","name":"Brestla"},"station":{"id":3224813312,"name":"Roed Odegaard Port"},"name":"SideWinder","alive":true,"id":14}}}
```

Python Code:

```
import json

with open('profile.txt') as edstats:
    data = json.load(edstats)

def shipYard():
    ships = [item["name"] for item in data['ships']]
    print json.dumps(ships,indent=4)
```

Error:

```
>>> shipYard()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "arg_test_ship.py", line 7, in shipYard
    ships = [item["name"] for item in data['ships']]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're missing is that data['ships'] is itself another dictionary object. When you iterate through a dictionary as you have in shipYard(), you will just get the keys:

```
>>> a={'a':1,'b':2}
... [i for i in a]
7: ['a','b']
```

You want to access the name attribute WITHIN the dictionary, for which you would use the dictionary.items() method:

```
>>> data = '''{"ships":{"2":{"name":"Asp","alive":true,"id":2},"3":{"starsystem":{"systemaddress":"670417429889","id":"670417429889","name":"Diaguandri"},"station":{"id":3223343616,"name":"Ray Gateway"},"name":"SideWinder","alive":true,"id":3},"12":{"starsystem":{"systemaddress":"18263140541865","id":"73228","name":"Barnard's Star"},"station":{"id":128147960,"name":"Miller Depot"},"name":"Viper_MkIV","alive":true,"id":12},"13":{"starsystem":{"systemaddress":"673101653409","id":"673101653409","name":"Brestla"},"station":{"id":3224813312,"name":"Roed Odegaard Port"},"name":"Type7","alive":true,"id":13},"14":{"starsystem":{"systemaddress":"673101653409","id":"673101653409","name":"Brestla"},"station":{"id":3224813312,"name":"Roed Odegaard Port"},"name":"SideWinder","alive":true,"id":14}}}'''
... import json
... data = json.loads(data)
>>> ships = [item['name'] for index, item in data['ships'].items()]
>>> ships
8: [u'Viper_MkIV', u'SideWinder', u'Asp', u'Type7', u'SideWinder']
>>>
```

Or, if you don't need the indexes, use the dictionary values() method:

```
>>> ships = [item['name'] for item in data['ships'].values()]
>>> ships
9: [u'Viper_MkIV', u'SideWinder', u'Asp', u'Type7', u'SideWinder']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me crazy

Comment: no worries. It does seem like one of those features which would be basically impossible to notice if you didn't know what was going on. A good rule of thumb I abide to is when using list comprehensions, if you're not getting what you'd expect, split it out into a for loop printing the results for each iteration, so you can see what's really going on.